# How to calculate the average of several .dat files using python?

Tags: python, file, average

So I have 50 - 60 .dat files all containing m rows and n columns of numbers. I need to take the average of all of the files and create a new file in the same format. I have to do this in python. Can anyone help me with this?

I've written some code..
I realize I have some incompatible types here, but I can't think of an alternative so I haven't change anything yet.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import os

CC = 1.96

average = []
total = []
count = 0
os.chdir("./")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".dat"):
        infile = open(files)
        cur = []
        cur = infile.readlines()
        for i in xrange(0, len(cur)):
            cur[i] = cur[i].split()
        total += cur
        count += 1
average = [x/count for x in total]

#calculate uncertainty
uncert = []

for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".dat"):
        infile = open(files)
        cur = []
        cur = infile.readlines
        for i in xrange(0, len(cur)):
            cur[i] = cur[i].split()
        uncert += (cur - average)**2
uncert = uncert**.5
uncert = uncert*CC
```

Comment: What the average of the files means is not obvious. Please post example files.

Comment: Think of each file being a matrix of the same dimensions. I want to determine the mean of all of the numbers at any given position in the matrices and then place the mean in this position in a matrix of averages.

Comment: What part are you specifically having the trouble with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fairly time- and resource-efficient approach which reads in the values and calculates their averages for all the files in parallel, yet only reads in one line per file at a time -- however it does temporarily read the entire first `.dat` file into memory in order to determine how many rows and columns of numbers are going to be in each file.

You didn't say if your "numbers" were integer or float or what, so this reads them in as floating point (which will work even if they're not). Regardless, the averages are calculated and output as floating point numbers.

**Update**

I've modified my original answer to also calculate a population standard deviation (`sigma`) of the values in each row and column, as per your comment. It does this right after it computes their mean value so a second pass to re-read the all the data isn't necessary. In addition, in response to a suggestion made in the comments, a context manager has been added to ensure that all the input files are get closed.

Note that the standard deviations are only printed and are not written to the output file, but doing that to the same or separate file should to be easy enough to add.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from itertools import izip
from glob import iglob
from math import sqrt
from sys import exit

@contextmanager
def multi_file_manager(files, mode='rt'):
    files = [open(file, mode) for file in files]
    yield files
    for file in files:
        file.close()

# generator function to read, convert, and yield each value from a text file
def read_values(file, datatype=float):
    for line in file:
        for value in (datatype(word) for word in line.split()):
            yield value

# enumerate multiple egual length iterables simultaneously as (i, n0, n1, ...)
def multi_enumerate(*iterables, **kwds):
    start = kwds.get('start', 0)
    return ((n,)+t for n, t in enumerate(izip(*iterables), start))

DATA_FILE_PATTERN = 'data*.dat'
MIN_DATA_FILES = 2

with multi_file_manager(iglob(DATA_FILE_PATTERN)) as datfiles:
    num_files = len(datfiles)
    if num_files < MIN_DATA_FILES:
        print('Less than {} .dat files were found to process, '
              'terminating.'.format(MIN_DATA_FILES))
        exit(1)

    # determine number of rows and cols from first file
    temp = [line.split() for line in datfiles[0]]
    num_rows = len(temp)
    num_cols = len(temp[0])
    datfiles[0].seek(0)  # rewind first file
    del temp  # no longer needed
    print '{} .dat files found, each must have {} rows x {} cols\n'.format(
           num_files, num_rows, num_cols)

    means = []
    std_devs = []
    divisor = float(num_files-1)  # Bessel's correction for sample standard dev
    generators = [read_values(file) for file in datfiles]
    for _ in xrange(num_rows):  # main processing loop
        for _ in xrange(num_cols):
            # create a sequence of next cell values from each file
            values = tuple(next(g) for g in generators)
            mean = float(sum(values)) / num_files
            means.append(mean)
            means_diff_sq = ((value-mean)**2 for value in values)
            std_dev = sqrt(sum(means_diff_sq) / divisor)
            std_devs.append(std_dev)

print 'Average and (standard deviation) of values:'
with open('means.txt', 'wt') as averages:
    for i, mean, std_dev in multi_enumerate(means, std_devs):
        print '{:.2f} ({:.2f})'.format(mean, std_dev),
        averages.write('{:.2f}'.format(mean))  # note std dev not written
        if i % num_cols != num_cols-1:  # not last column?
             averages.write(' ')  # delimiter between values on line
        else:
            print  # newline
            averages.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome. I never would have thought to use a generator. If I was going to go back and calculate the standard deviation in the same manner as the averages, would you suggest I use another generator?

Comment: Yes, using a list of generators ought to work fine for calculating the σ of each cell. Instead of closing each file at the end, you could rewinding each one in the `files` list with a `files[i].seek(0)` and then create a new `generators` list. If you've got enough memory, it would of course be much faster to save all the data read in during the first pass.

Comment: Much better idea: You could calculate the σ right in the inner loop where only the `average` is currently being computed by making `values` a regular sequence (list or tuple) rather than using a generator expression as it does in the above. That would mean being able to compute both metrics in a single pass.

Comment: My only addition to this would be to use a `with` statement to ensure files are closed.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Good point. I skipped doing that before you mentioned it now because it seemed complicated given the list of open files -- but have now added it because it turned out to not really be that difficult after all.

Comment: I had a couple questions.
Shouldn't sigma equal 'sqrt(sum(means_diff_sq)/ (num_files-1)'?
Also, I'm getting an StopIteration error on the 'values = map(next, generators)' statement. Should I change this back to a tuple?

Comment: @user1757550: Dividing by (num-files-1) might be correct (see [population vs sample std dev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Basic_examples)). Changing the `map()` call back to `tuple()` form should be equivalent -- I don't get `StopIteration` exceptions with the former myself, and am not sure why you would.

Comment: P.S. If you end up changing the divisor to `num_files-1`, move the calculation of it outside the main loop and store a `float()` version of it in a new variable which is then used inside in its place instead.

Comment: P.P.S Another thing about using `num_files-1` is that a minimum of two .dat files will then be required (`num_files` must be > 1), otherwise a `ZeroDivisionError` will occur.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which aspect of the process is giving you the problem, but I will just answer specifically about getting the averages of all the dat files.

Assuming a data structure like this:

```
72 12 94 79 76  5 30 98 97 48 
79 95 63 74 70 18 92 20 32 50 
77 88 60 98 19 17 14 66 80 24 
...
```

Getting averages of the files:

```
import glob
import itertools

avgs = []

for datpath in glob.iglob("*.dat"):
    with open(datpath, 'r') as f:
        str_nums = itertools.chain.from_iterable(i.strip().split() for i in f)
        nums = map(int, str_nums)
        avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
        avgs.append(avg)

print avgs
```

It loops over each `.dat` file, reads and joins the lines. Converts them to int (could be float if you want) and appends the avg.

If these files are enormous and you are concerned about the amount of memory when reading them in, you could more explicitly loop over each line and only keep counter, the way your original example was doing:

```
for datpath in glob.iglob("*.dat"):
    with open(datpath, 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        total = 0
        for line in f:
            nums = [int(i) for i in line.strip().split()]
            count += len(nums)
            total += sum(nums)
        avgs.append(total / count)
```

- Note: I am not handling exceptional cases, such as the file being empty and producing a Divide By Zero situation.